# How to build typeorm entities (and related) using webpack 5 and ts-loader?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typeorm

I have been trying to build typeorm entities, migrations and subscribers using webpack 5 and ts-loader, but I am having several issues. I am misunderstanding something in this webpack setup, so I created a replication package on GitHub at [this link](https://github.com/saulotoledo/typeorm-webpack5-build-investigation) based on the [typescript example provided by the typeorm developers](https://github.com/typeorm/typescript-example).

I need to run typeorm migrations commands with the files built with webpack. However, by running "migration:show" I have the following result:

```bash
$>npm run migration:show   

> typeorm-typescript-example@0.0.1 migration:show
> ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm -d dist/database/data-source.js migration:show

Error during migration show:
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/temp/dist/database/entity/Category.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext (/workspace/temp/dist/database/data-source.js:91:10)
    at tryToRequire (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:72119:41)
    at importOrRequireFile (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:72133:24)
    at async /workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:108981:41
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async importClassesFromDirectories (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:108984:18)
    at async ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:108912:17)
    at async DataSource.buildMetadatas (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:72720:33)
    at async DataSource.initialize (/workspace/temp/dist/database/common.js:72401:13)
    at async Object.handler (/workspace/temp/node_modules/typeorm/commands/MigrationShowCommand.js:35:13) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

The file exists and contains the class. Note that the stack trace prints "tryToRequire", but the file seems to work with imports. I can't use `type: "module"` in my package.json due to compatibility with my main application. I need the output to be commonjs. There are several mode.exports from webpack in my final bundle. My tsconfig.json file is as follows (I added a few comments below to highlight some pieces of the config):

```json
{
    "version": "2.4.2",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["@types/node"],
        "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Regarding the example source code, it contains 2 entities and a config file. It is mandatory for new typeorm versions that the config file exports a DataSource object. The final webpack config is as follows:

```json
[
  {
    // Full build output enabled:
    stats: 'verbose',
    mode: 'none',
    entry: {
      './src/entity/Category.ts': {
        import: './src/entity/Category.ts',
        filename: './entity/Category.js'
      },
      './src/entity/Post.ts': {
        import: './src/entity/Post.ts',
        filename: './entity/Post.js'
      },
      './src/data-source.ts': {
        import: './src/data-source.ts',
        filename: './data-source.js'
      }
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
      path: '/workspace/temp/dist/database',
      filename: '[name].js',

      // I need the final bundle compatible with commonjs:
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },
    ignoreWarnings: [ /^(?!CriticalDependenciesWarning$)/ ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.html?$/, use: 'ignore-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                transpileOnly: true,
                configFile: 'tsconfig.json',

                // Should I need the line below?
                compilerOptions: { module: 'commonjs' }
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          // Builds a "common.js" file with code shared among many entities.
          // This will reduce code duplication in the final bundle:
          common: {
            name: 'common',
            test: /node_modules/,
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ], alias: {} },
    plugins: [
      IgnorePlugin {
        options: { checkResource: (resource, _context) => {

          // First tentative to ignore optional dependencies. Webpack should not
          // require them. I did not fully understand why I need this yet, but
          // it is not my main problem here. Solving this will be a bonus:

          // return ['mssql', 'react-native-sqlite-storage', 'sql.js', 'sqlite3', 'better-sqlite3', 'ioredis', 'redis', 'typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver', 'pg-native', 'pg-query-stream', 'oracledb', 'mysql2', 'mysql', 'hdb-pool', '@sap/hana-client', 'mongodb', '@google-cloud/spanner', 'react-native-sqlite-storage'].some((value) => resource.includes(value));
        } },
      },
      NormalModuleReplacementPlugin {

        // Alternative way to solve the problem above: replacing it with an empty module.
        // Again, it will be a bonus if we solve this in a better way, but it is not
        // the main problem:

        resourceRegExp: /(mssql|react-native-sqlite-storage|sqlite3|better-sqlite3|ioredis|redis|typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver|oracledb|mysql2|mysql|hdb-pool|@sap\/hana-client|mongodb|@google-cloud\/spanner|react-native-sqlite-storage)/,
        newResource: '/workspace/temp/empty-module.js'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can also see this final configuration after running webpack. I added a log to the end of the webpack config with it.

The [example in Github](https://github.com/saulotoledo/typeorm-webpack5-build-investigation) contains a docker container with a sample postgres database and can be build/tested as follows:

```
npm install
npm run build
npm run migration:show
```

Could you help me to understand what is wrong with this setup?